# Getting Newly Added Entities AFTER SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a process that needs the Primary Key ID of a newly added Entity every time an Entity is added. I have overriden the `SaveChanges()` method of `DbContext`, and looked at the `ChangeTracker`, but I don't see any dynamic way to retrieve the Entities that are newly added. Is there a good method to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query the change tracker for new entities.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var newEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                        .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                        .Select(entry => entry.Entity).ToList();

    var count = base.SaveChanges();

    // do something with newEntities

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override SaveChanges and collect any entities in the Added state prior to the actual save, but that's about it AFAIK.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Entities don't have the Primary Key value at this point.

Comment: Not sure I understand. As you can see in Eranga's example, you store the entities that are added, then do something after they are saved. If they are assigned primary key values by the database, the same entities will be updated and you will have the keys.